# Ruby: How to specify character encoding of the file in the command line (-Eex[:in] option)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I cannot set the encoding for a file, all the time I get an error. I've tried all the ways:

```
C:\ruby\sbox>ruby -W3 -Eex=utf-8 gserver.rb text.txt
ruby: unknown encoding name - ex=utf-8 (RuntimeError)

C:\ruby\sbox>ruby -W3 -Eex=utf8 gserver.rb text.txt
ruby: unknown encoding name - ex=utf8 (RuntimeError)

C:\ruby\sbox>ruby -W3 -Eex:utf8 gserver.rb text.txt
ruby: unknown encoding name - ex (RuntimeError)

C:\ruby\sbox>ruby -W3 -Eex=>utf8 gserver.rb text.txt
ruby: unknown encoding name - ex= (RuntimeError)

C:\ruby\sbox>ruby -W3 -Eex=>utf-8 gserver.rb text.txt
ruby: unknown encoding name - ex= (RuntimeError)

C:\ruby\sbox>ruby -W3 -Eexutf-8 gserver.rb text.txt
ruby: unknown encoding name - exutf-8 (RuntimeError)

C:\ruby\sbox>ruby -W3 -Eex"utf-8" gserver.rb text.txt
ruby: unknown encoding name - exutf-8 (RuntimeError)

C:\ruby\sbox>ruby -W3 -Eex="utf-8" gserver.rb text.txt
ruby: unknown encoding name - ex=utf-8 (RuntimeError)
```

How to set this option?

[This reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_command_line_options.htm) doesn't have `-Eex` option.

**UPD:**

I've learned how. No need to print that `ex`. Just `-Eutf-8:cp866`

```
C:\ruby\sbox>ruby -W3 -Eutf-8:cp866 gserver.rb text.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also the `-K` option, which seems to work better for me than the `-E` option. It will set the internal (script) and external encoding. The ruby(1) man page states:

```
  -K kcode
          Specifies KANJI (Japanese) encoding. The default value for
          script encodings ("__ENCODING__") and external encodings
          ("Encoding.default_external") will be the specified one.  kcode
          can be one of

   e      EUC-JP


   s      Windows-31J (CP932)


   u      UTF-8


   n      ASCII-8BIT (BINARY)
```

To run my wiki, I use:

```
$ ruby -Ku wiki.rb
```

My ruby wiki source files are all ASCII, but sometimes when I copy and paste from the web to my wiki, some characters are UTF-8. Without setting the `-K` option, I get "*ArgumentError - invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII*" for some pages of my wiki.

But

```
$ ruby -Eutf-8 wiki.rb
```

also works.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the 'magic comment' at the top of your file:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```