# In ruby, change a script's default string encoding at run time?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, runtime

I know that I can invoke a `ruby` script as follows to set the default string encoding which will be in effect when running the script ...

```
ruby -Eencoding script.rb args ...
```

However, is there some call that I could make inside of `script.rb` itself to set the encoding in the same way, if I run the script directly as follows, instead of via a call to the `ruby` interpreter? ...

```
./script.rb args ...
```

In other words, I want all string operations that are performed when `script.rb` is running to make use of an encoding that I specify ***at run time*** inside of `script.rb`. This includes all string operations that are performed inside of the ruby methods and functions and internals that are called when `script.rb` is executing.

For example, assume that I implement an optional `-e` command-line argument to `script.rb` which will contain the name of an encoding, such as `ISO-8859-1` or `UTF-8` or any other valid encoding. I could then run the script as follows:

```
./script.rb -eISO-8859-1 args ...
```

And another time, I might run that same script like this:

```
./script.rb -eUTF-8 args ...
```

Inside of the script, I could use `OptionParser` or `GetOptLong` or some other code to parse the command-line arguments and extract that optional encoding argument. If that argument has been passed in, I want to then call some sort of `ruby` function to set that to be the encoding used in all subsequent string operations, including operations in all `ruby` internal methods, functions, and modules.

I could not find any discussion of any such function in `ruby`. Does such a function even exist in `ruby`?

Also, I don't want to have to set an environment variable outside of `script.rb` in order to tell it which string encoding to utilize. I want this choice of string encoding to be made via some sort of executable `ruby` code that I invoke at run time, from ***inside*** of `script.rb`.

Thank you in advance for any ideas and suggestions.

**UPDATE**: I tried setting ruby's `default_internal` coding per the suggestion by @Stefan, but it doesn't work.  Here's some sample code which illustrates the problem ...

```
#!/opt/local/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/bin/ruby                                                                                                               
# -*- ruby -*-                                                                                                                                        

Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::ISO_8859_1

require 'optparse'

parser = OptionParser.new {
}
parser.parse!

Process.exit(0)
```

Assume this code is in a file called `rtest.rb`, and assume that `LC_TYPE` and `LC_CTYPE` are set to 'UTF-8' in the environment. And assume that I have a file in my current directory whose name is encoded as a `ISO-8859-1` string. Then, I run the script as follows:

```
./rtest.rb *
```

What results is this error:

```
/opt/local/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0+0/optparse.rb:1640:in `===': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /opt/local/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0+0/optparse.rb:1640:in `block in parse_in_order'
    from /opt/local/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0+0/optparse.rb:1636:in `catch'
    from /opt/local/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0+0/optparse.rb:1636:in `parse_in_order'
    from /opt/local/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0+0/optparse.rb:1630:in `order!'
    from /opt/local/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0+0/optparse.rb:1739:in `permute!'
    from /opt/local/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0+0/optparse.rb:1764:in `parse!'
    from ./rtest.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

**FURTHER UPDATE**: I completely unset all of the `LC_*` environment variables, and I then re-ran. I got the same error.

Comment: Like this? `Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8`

Comment: Thank you very much, but that doesn't seem to work once the ruby interpreter has been started. Even when I set it right at the top of my script, it doesn't affect any of the string operations that take place inside the script.

Comment: @Stefan I was going to comment the same but this is not a runtime configuration per se. Either way OP here are the [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/syntax/comments_rdoc.html#label-Magic+Comments) for "magic comments" if it suits your needs.

Comment: @HippoMan `Encoding.default_internal = ...` _does_ change the encoding. You probably inspect string _literals_ inside the script which will always have a fixed encoding – either UTF-8 (default) or the one set by the magic `# encoding: ...` comment. Can you give an example of your _"string operations"_?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I set `Encoding.default_internal = ...` at the top of the script. Inside the script, I parse the command line arguments with `OptionParser`. If any of the arguments are encoded as `ISO-8859-1` strings and if the session is running with `LC_TYPE` and `LC_CTYPE` as `UTF-8`, then I get the following error from the option parser, no matter how I set `Encoding.default_internal` ... `Unable to parse this command-line argument: ["... etc. ..."]` . But if I set the environment variables `LC_TYPE` and `LC_CTYPE` to `ISO-8859-1`, then the argument parsing works with no problem.

Comment: Actually, I now realize that the above error message came from an error handler that I wrote. See the **UPDATE** that I just now posted above for a short program without any special error handler, and which illustrates the exact problem that I'm reporting.

Comment: So this just became a duplicate of your [previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75537424/in-ruby-optparse-raises-error-when-filename-contains-certain-characters)?

Comment: Well, that wasn't my original intention. With this issue, I was hoping that I could find some way to change ruby's internal encoding at run time. Then, if I was successful, I was going to go back to the other issue and offer a solution based on what I would have learned here.  However, given that after asking here, it seems that such a way to change the internal encoding is impossible, I now see that these are just two manifestations of the same issue.

Comment: @HippoMan you should be able to technically create a script that accepts the encoding. You could then execute the current script with the encoding argument and forward the rest of the arguments to the current script.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. However, this example with `OptionParser` is just that ... an example. There are other routines within ruby that exhibit the same behavior: for example, `File.realpath`, and I'm sure that there are others.

Comment: One more clarifying point: I wrote a ruby script that runs under 4 OS's on various hosts: Ubuntu, Debian, RedHat, and MacOS. The ruby interpreter on each host is built slightly differently. The code works very well on all these platforms, *except* for encoding-specific issues. I do not want to put host-specific encoding code into each version. Ideally, I'd like the script to figure out how to do the encoding in each case. But many of the encoding problems occur within internal ruby modules themselves, and so it seems impossible for me to get this script to work in a host-independent manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should file a bug to the Ruby devs. `OptionParser` shouldn't crash because of encoding problems when dealing with paths. A path can contain any byte (excluding the `NUL` byte), so `OptionParser::!parse` shall always deal with them as `ASCII-8BIT`, independently of the encoding that you choose for the program.

**edit:** As a workaround, I would recommend to override the encoding of the arguments manually:

```rb
ARGV.map! { |s| s.dup.force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT).freeze }
```

Second, the only way that I found for setting the internal encoding of the ruby interpreter "**from inside**" `script.rb` is to add an option to the shebang. Though it'll only work when calling the script as an executable.

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby -EASCII-8BIT
```

<sup>**warning:** a shebang only accepts one argument; for example `#!/usr/bin/env ruby -EASCII-8BIT` doesn't work</sup>

---

Now, for passing the encoding as an argument to the script, there's no other way than to wrap the program in an other script. Here's an example with a shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

cat <<'EOF' | ruby "$@"

require 'optparse'

parser = OptionParser.new { }
parser.parse!

Process.exit(0)

EOF
```

Then you can call it like this:

```bash
./script.sh -EASCII-8BIT -- filename_with_non_utf8_characters ...
```

Comment: Yes, I came up with something similar. See one of my "Answers" here (the one where I discuss `ruby-preproc`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75537424/in-ruby-optparse-raises-error-when-filename-contains-certain-characters

Comment: And yes, I agree that it's a good idea to file a bug with the Ruby devs. I'll do that over the weekend.

Comment: @HippoMan I added a workaround that might be useful

Comment: Yes, your workaround makes sense.  Also, did you check out my version of this here? ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75537424/in-ruby-optparse-raises-error-when-filename-contains-certain-characters .  Look for the "Answer" whose text starts with "I came up with this slightly hacky workaround ...".  In this "Answer", I use a slightly different way to manage the shebang issue.